# How to solve file permission issues when developing with Apache HTTP server in Docker?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, apache2, signals, file-permissions

My Dockerfile extends from `php:8.1-apache`. The following happens while developing:

- The application creates log files (as `www-data`, `33:33`)
- I create files (as the image's default user `root`, `0:0`) within the container

These files are mounted on my host where I'm acting as `user` (`1000:1000`). Of course I'm running into file permission issues now. I'd like to update/delete files created in the container on my host and vice versa.

---

My current solution is to set the image's user to `www-data`. In that way, all created files belong to it. Then, I change its user and group id from `33` to `1000`. That solves my file permission issues.

However, this leads to another problem:
I'm prepending `sudo -E` to the entrypoint and command. I'm doing that because they're normally running as root and my custom entrypoint requires root permissions. **But in that way the stop signal stops working** and the container has to be killed when I want it to stop:

```bash
~$ time docker-compose down
Stopping test_app ... done
Removing test_app ... done
Removing network test_default

real    0m10,645s
user    0m0,167s
sys     0m0,004s
```

Here's my Dockerfile:

```bash
FROM php:8.1-apache AS base

FROM base AS dev
COPY entrypoint.dev.sh /usr/local/bin/custom-entrypoint.sh

ARG user_id=1000
ARG group_id=1000

RUN set -xe \
    # Create a home directory for www-data
    && mkdir --parents /home/www-data \
    && chown --recursive www-data:www-data /home/www-data \
    # Make www-data's user and group id match my host user's ones (1000 and 1000)
    && usermod --home /home/www-data --uid $user_id www-data \
    && groupmod --gid $group_id www-data \
    # Add sudo and let www-data execute it without asking for a password
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install --yes --no-install-recommends sudo \
    && rm --recursive --force /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && echo "www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" > /etc/sudoers.d/www-data

USER www-data

# Run entrypoint and command as sudo, as my entrypoint does some config substitution and both normally run as root
ENTRYPOINT [ "sudo", "-E", "custom-entrypoint.sh" ]
CMD [ "sudo", "-E", "apache2-foreground" ]
```

Here's my custom-entrypoint.sh

```bash
#!/bin/sh
set -e

sed --in-place 's@^RemoteIPTrustedProxy.*@RemoteIPTrustedProxy '"$REMOTEIP_TRUSTED_PROXY"'@' $APACHE_CONFDIR/conf-available/remoteip.conf

exec docker-php-entrypoint "$@"
```

What do I need to do to make the container catch the stop signal (it is `SIGWINCH` for the Apache server) again? Or is there a better way to handle the file permission issues, so I don't need to run the entrypoint and command with `sudo -E`?

Comment: You don't need `sudo` in Docker at all; don't even install it.  If you want the main container process to run as root, specify `USER root` at the end instead of a different user.

Comment: `root` is the default user, so `USER root` wouldn't even be necessary. But when I go into the container (`docker-compose exec app bash`) and create a file (`touch test`) the file belongs to `root` and I'm not able to modify/delete it on the host.

Comment: You can edit files directly on the host, without indirectly getting a debugging shell inside the container.  Or you can `docker-compose exec -u` an alternate user.

Comment: The actual way I'm creating files in the container is using Laravel's `make` command: `php artisan make:model User`. That will create a new class file with a blueprint. I can't run that command on my host because there's no PHP installed. If I used `docker-compose exec -u www-data` instead of my current solution, `www-data` would still have a user and group id of `33`, so the permissions with my host user still wouldn't match. Furthermore, I must not forget to type `-u www-data` every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What do I need to do to make the container catch the stop signal (it is SIGWINCH for the Apache server) again?

First, get rid of `sudo`, if you need to be root in your container, run it as root with `USER root` in your Dockerfile. There's little value add to `sudo` in the container since it should be an environment to run one app and not a multi-user general purpose Linux host.

> Or is there a better way to handle the file permission issues, so I don't need to run the entrypoint and command with sudo -E?

The pattern I go with is to have developers launch the container as root, and have the entrypoint detect the uid/gid of the mounted volume, and adjust the uid/gid of the user in the container to match that id before running `gosu` to drop permissions and run as that user. I've included a lot of this logic in my [base image example](https://github.com/sudo-bmitch/docker-base) (note the [fix-perms script](https://github.com/sudo-bmitch/docker-base/blob/main/bin/fix-perms) that tweaks the uid/gid). Another example of that pattern is in my [jenkins-docker](https://github.com/sudo-bmitch/jenkins-docker) image.

You'll still need to either configure root's login shell to automatically run `gosu` inside the container, or remember to always pass `-u www-data` when you exec into your image, but now that uid/gid will match your host.

This is primarily for development. In production, you probably don't want host volumes, use named volumes instead, or at least hardcode the uid/gid of the user in the image to match the desired id on the production hosts. That means the Dockerfile would still have `USER www-data` but the docker-compose.yml for developers would have `user: root` that doesn't exist in the compose file in production. You can find a bit more on this in my [DockerCon 2019 talk](https://sudo-bmitch.github.io/presentations/dc2019/tips-and-tricks-of-the-captains.html#fix-perms) ([video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=woBI466WMR8&list=PLkA60AVN3hh-XtoZ8zoZir6wnpaVXGUgk)).

Comment: Thanks, I've watched your talk and read some posts about `gosu` (from which some were written by you) and pulled in your fix-perms script! I'm left with two issues: 1.) Tools like Composer/Maven create a cache in the user's home dir. So I still need to create `/home/www-data` and give it to `www-data`, right? Or how do you handle this? 2.) I can't find a way to configure `root`'s login shell to act as `www-data`  when running `docker-compose exec app bash`. Do you have a hint for me?

Comment: @user10517872 1 - yes, you'll want the home directory in the container, when fix-perms modifiers the uid in the container /etc/passwd, it also adjusts files owned by that uid. 2 - that should be possible with an entry in /root/.bashrc in the container to do something like an `exec gosu www-data bash`. I'd check for the "interactive" check that's normally in the file, and add your command after that check.

Comment: 1.) `/var/www` is `www-data`'s default home, but owned by `root`. I'm mounting my files into `/var/www/html`. A simple `chown` solves the problem and I don't have to create a new home under `/home/www-data`! 2.) I tried to add that to `/root/.profile` all the time! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [user namespace](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/userns-remap/) to map different user/group in your docker to you on the host.

For example, the group `www-data`/`33` in the container could be the group `docker-www-data`/`100033` on the host, you just have be in the group to access log files.

Comment: Thanks! It seems that it takes pretty much configuration to get started with this. It's unlikely a colleague will read the docs and set up the remapping when he needs to make changes to my project. I will definitely try this though!